# what is js code of integral sin(x) function?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, integral

I try to write a simple integral for sin(x) function. Normally integral of sin(x) from 0, to pi equals to 2, but my js code gives me 114. what is problem with my code?

```js
let i = 0
let total = 0;
for(i=0; i<=180; i++ ) {
    total += Math.sin(i*(Math.PI/180))
}
console.log(total)
```

Comment: Integral of sin(x) is -cos(x)

Comment: If you think of this as a sum of rectangles, then you correctly determine that the _height_ of each rectangle is `Math.sin(i * (Math.PI / 180))`, but you forgot to consider the _width_ of each rectangle; it’s not `1`. You’re subdividing `Math.PI` into 180 parts, so you have to multiply each term by `(Math.PI / 180)`. The result is `1.9999492301722783`. Actually, you’re counting 181 parts; the loop condition should be `i < 180`.

Answer (score 1):

Taking @SebastianSimon's comment, we find:

> If you think of this as a sum of rectangles, then you correctly determine that the height of each rectangle is `Math.sin(i * (Math.PI / 180))`, but you forgot to consider the width of each rectangle - which is not 1. You’re subdividing `Math.PI` into 180 parts, so you have to multiply each term by `Math.PI / 180`.

```js
let total = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 180; i++) { // i < 180, not i <= 180
    total += Math.sin(i * (Math.PI / 180)) * (Math.PI / 180);
    //                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ width of each rectangle
    //       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ height of each rectangle
}

console.log(total); // VERY CLOSE to 2
```

However, you'll notice that the end result is not exactly equal to 2, but very close to it. This is because of floating point arithmetic; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Well, almost all of the numeric error comes from the low approximation of 180 subdivisions.

Comment: We general use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken as the link for floating point issues, to keep it inside the site.